# jQuery mCustomScrollbar issue

Tags: jquery

I'm Using jQuery custom scollbar and I'm having issue with scroll working. 
Problem is that it appears only when I press F12 (firebug). How to make it work without turning firebug on?

Some html code from page:

```
<div class="mCSB_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px;"><div class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light" id="mCSB_2" style="position:relative; height:100%; overflow:hidden; max-width:100%;"><div class="mCSB_container mCS_no_scrollbar" style="position: relative; top: 0px;"><p>
    <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></p>
<p>

<p>
    <strong></strong></p>
<ul>
    <li>
        Content Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>
        Content Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>
        Content Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
<p>
    <strong>DContent Lorem Ipsum</strong></p>
<ul>
    <li>
        Content Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>
    Content Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>
        SContent Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>
        Content Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>
        Content Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>
        Content Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
<p>
Content Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>
Content Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>
    Content Lorem Ipsum</p>


    &nbsp;</p>
</div><div class="mCSB_scrollTools" style="position: absolute; display: none;"><div class="mCSB_draggerContainer"><div class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;" oncontextmenu="return false;"><div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="position:relative;"></div></div><div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div></div></div></div></div>
```

And scrollbar.js

```
/*mousewheel*/
(function(a){function d(b){var c=b||window.event,d=[].slice.call(arguments,1),e=0,f=!0,g=0,h=0;return b=a.event.fix(c),b.type="mousewheel",c.wheelDelta&&(e=c.wheelDelta/120),c.detail&&(e=-c.detail/3),h=e,c.axis!==undefined&&c.axis===c.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(h=0,g=-1*e),c.wheelDeltaY!==undefined&&(h=c.wheelDeltaY/120),c.wheelDeltaX!==undefined&&(g=-1*c.wheelDeltaX/120),d.unshift(b,e,g,h),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,d)}var b=["DOMMouseScroll","mousewheel"];if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var c=b.length;c;)a.event.fixHooks[b[--c]]=a.event.mouseHooks;a.event.special.mousewheel={setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.addEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=d},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.removeEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null}},a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})})(jQuery);
/*custom scrollbar*/
(function(c){var b={init:function(e){var f={set_width:false,set_height:false,horizontalScroll:false,scrollInertia:950,mouseWheel:true,mouseWheelPixels:"auto",autoDraggerLength:true,autoHideScrollbar:false,snapAmount:null,snapOffset:0,scrollButtons:{enable:false,scrollType:"continuous",scrollSpeed:"auto",scrollAmount:40},advanced:{updateOnBrowserResize:true,updateOnContentResize:false,autoExpandHorizontalScroll:false,autoScrollOnFocus:true,normalizeMouseWheelDelta:false},contentTouchScroll:true,callbacks:{onScrollStart:function(){},onScroll:function(){},onTotalScroll:function(){},onTotalScrollBack:function(){},onTotalScrollOffset:0,onTotalScrollBackOffset:0,whileScrolling:function(){}},theme:"light"},e=c.extend(true,f,e);return this.each(function(){var m=c(this);if(e.set_width){m.css("width",e.set_width)}if(e.set_height){m.css("height",e.set_height)}if(!c(document).data("mCustomScrollbar-index")){c(document).data("mCustomScrollbar-index","1")}else{var t=parseInt(c(document).data("mCustomScrollbar-index"));c(document).data("mCustomScrollbar-index",t+1)}m.wrapInner("<div class='mCustomScrollBox mCS-"+e.theme+"' id='mCSB_"+c(document).data("mCustomScrollbar-index")+"' style='position:relative; height:100%; overflow:hidden; max-width:100%;' />").addClass("mCustomScrollbar _mCS_"+c(document).data("mCustomScrollbar-index"));var g=m.children(".mCustomScrollBox");if(e.horizontalScroll){g.addClass("mCSB_horizontal").wrapInner("<div class='mCSB_h_wrapper' style='position:relative; left:0; width:999999px;' />");var k=g.children(".mCSB_h_wrapper");k.wrapInner("<div class='mCSB_container' style='position:absolute; left:0;' />").children(".mCSB_container").css({width:k.children().outerWidth(),position:"relative"}).unwrap()}else{g.wrapInner("<div class='mCSB_container' style='position:relative; top:0;' />")}var o=g.children(".mCSB_container");if(c.support.touch){o.addClass("mCS_touch")}o.after("<div class='mCSB_scrollTools' style='position:absolute;'><div class='mCSB_draggerContainer'><div class='mCSB_dragger' style='position:absolute;' oncontextmenu='return false;'><div class='mCSB_dragger_bar' style='position:relative;'></div></div><div class='mCSB_draggerRail'></div></div></div>");var l=g.children(".mCSB_scrollTools"),h=l.children(".mCSB_draggerContainer"),q=h.children(".mCSB_dragger");if(e.horizontalScroll){q.data("minDraggerWidth",q.width())}else{q.data("minDraggerHeight",q.height())}if(e.scrollButtons.enable){if(e.horizontalScroll){l.prepend("<a class='mCSB_buttonLeft' oncontextmenu='return false;'></a>").append("<a class='mCSB_buttonRight' oncontextmenu='return false;'></a>")}else{l.prepend("<a class='mCSB_buttonUp' oncontextmenu='return false;'></a>").append("<a class='mCSB_buttonDown' oncontextmenu='return false;'></a>")}}g.bind("scroll",function(){if(!m.is(".mCS_disabled")){g.scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0)}});m.data({mCS_Init:true,mCustomScrollbarIndex:c(document).data("mCustomScrollbar-index"),horizontalScroll:e.horizontalScroll,scrollInertia:e.scrollInertia,scrollEasing:"mcsEaseOut",mouseWheel:e.mouseWheel,mouseWheelPixels:e.mouseWheelPixels,autoDraggerLength:e.autoDraggerLength,autoHideScrollbar:e.autoHideScrollbar,snapAmount:e.snapAmount,snapOffset:e.snapOffset,scrollButtons_enable:e.scrollButtons.enable,scrollButtons_scrollType:e.scrollButtons.scrollType,scrollButtons_scrollSpeed:e.scrollButtons.scrollSpeed,scrollButtons_scrollAmount:e.scrollButtons.scrollAmount,autoExpandHorizontalScroll:e.advanced.autoExpandHorizontalScroll,autoScrollOnFocus:e.advanced.autoScrollOnFocus,normalizeMouseWheelDelta:e.advanced.normalizeMouseWheelDelta,contentTouchScroll:e.contentTouchScroll,onScrollStart_Callback:e.callbacks.onScrollStart,onScroll_Callback:e.callbacks.onScroll,onTotalScroll_Callback:e.callbacks.onTotalScroll,onTotalScrollBack_Callback:e.callbacks.onTotalScrollBack,onTotalScroll_Offset:e.callbacks.onTotalScrollOffset,onTotalScrollBack_Offset:e.callbacks.onTotalScrollBackOffset,whileScrolling_Callback:e.callbacks.whileScrolling,bindEvent_scrollbar_drag:false,bindEvent_content_touch:false,bindEvent_scrollbar_click:false,bindEvent_mousewheel:false,bindEvent_buttonsContinuous_y:false,bindEvent_buttonsContinuous_x:false,bindEvent_buttonsPixels_y:false,bindEvent_buttonsPixels_x:false,bindEvent_focusin:false,bindEvent_autoHideScrollbar:false,mCSB_buttonScrollRight:false,mCSB_buttonScrollLeft:false,mCSB_buttonScrollDown:false,mCSB_buttonScrollUp:false});if(e.horizontalScroll){if(m.css("max-width")!=="none"){if(!e.advanced.updateOnContentResize){e.advanced.updateOnContentResize=true}}}else{if(m.css("max-height")!=="none"){var s=false,r=parseInt(m.css("max-height"));if(m.css("max-height").indexOf("%")>=0){s=r,r=m.parent().height()*s/100}m.css("overflow","hidden");g.css("max-height",r)}}m.mCustomScrollbar("update");if(e.advanced.updateOnBrowserResize){var i,j=c(window).width(),u=c(window).height();c(window).bind("resize."+m.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex"),function(){if(i){clearTimeout(i)}i=setTimeout(function(){if(!m.is(".mCS_disabled")&&!m.is(".mCS_destroyed")){var w=c(window).width(),v=c(window).height();if(j!==w||u!==v){if(m.css("max-height")!=="none"&&s){g.css("max-height",m.parent().height()*s/100)}m.mCustomScrollbar("update");j=w;u=v}}},150)})}if(e.advanced.updateOnContentResize){var p;if(e.horizontalScroll){var n=o.outerWidth()}else{var n=o.outerHeight()}p=setInterval(function(){if(e.horizontalScroll){if(e.advanced.autoExpandHorizontalScroll){o.css({position:"absolute",width:"auto"}).wrap("<div class='mCSB_h_wrapper' style='position:relative; left:0; width:999999px;' />").css({width:o.outerWidth(),position:"relative"}).unwrap()}var v=o.outerWidth()}else{var v=o.outerHeight()}if(v!=n){m.mCustomScrollbar("update");n=v}},300)}})},update:function(){var n=c(this),k=n.children(".mCustomScrollBox"),q=k.children(".mCSB_container");q.removeClass("mCS_no_scrollbar");n.removeClass("mCS_disabled mCS_destroyed");k.scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0);var y=k.children(".mCSB_scrollTools"),o=y.children(".mCSB_draggerContainer"),m=o.children(".mCSB_dragger");if(n.data("horizontalScroll")){var A=y.children(".mCSB_buttonLeft"),t=y.children(".mCSB_buttonRight"),f=k.width();if(n.data("autoExpandHorizontalScroll")){q.css({position:"absolute",width:"auto"}).wrap("<div class='mCSB_h_wrapper' style='position:relative; left:0; width:999999px;' />").css({width:q.outerWidth(),position:"relative"}).unwrap()}var z=q.outerWidth()}else{var w=y.children(".mCSB_buttonUp"),g=y.children(".mCSB_buttonDown"),r=k.height(),i=q.outerHeight()}if(i>r&&!n.data("horizontalScroll")){y.css("display","block");var s=o.height();if(n.data("autoDraggerLength")){var u=Math.round(r/i*s),l=m.data("minDraggerHeight");if(u<=l){m.css({height:l})}else{if(u>=s-10){var p=s-10;m.css({height:p})}else{m.css({height:u})}}m.children(".mCSB_dragger_bar").css({"line-height":m.height()+"px"})}var B=m.height(),x=(i-r)/(s-B);n.data("scrollAmount",x).mCustomScrollbar("scrolling",k,q,o,m,w,g,A,t);var D=Math.abs(q.position().top);n.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",D,{scrollInertia:0,trigger:"internal"})}else{if(z>f&&n.data("horizontalScroll")){y.css("display","block");var h=o.width();if(n.data("autoDraggerLength")){var j=Math.round(f/z*h),C=m.data("minDraggerWidth");if(j<=C){m.css({width:C})}else{if(j>=h-10){var e=h-10;m.css({width:e})}else{m.css({width:j})}}}var v=m.width(),x=(z-f)/(h-v);n.data("scrollAmount",x).mCustomScrollbar("scrolling",k,q,o,m,w,g,A,t);var D=Math.abs(q.position().left);n.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",D,{scrollInertia:0,trigger:"internal"})}else{k.unbind("mousewheel focusin");if(n.data("horizontalScroll")){m.add(q).css("left",0)}else{m.add(q).css("top",0)}y.css("display","none");q.addClass("mCS_no_scrollbar");n.data({bindEvent_mousewheel:false,bindEvent_focusin:false})}}},scrolling:function(h,p,m,j,w,e,A,v){var k=c(this);if(!k.data("bindEvent_scrollbar_drag")){var n,o;if(c.support.msPointer){j.bind("MSPointerDown",function(H){H.preventDefault();k.data({on_drag:true});j.addClass("mCSB_dragger_onDrag");var G=c(this),J=G.offset(),F=H.originalEvent.pageX-J.left,I=H.originalEvent.pageY-J.top;if(F<G.width()&&F>0&&I<G.height()&&I>0){n=I;o=F}});c(document).bind("MSPointerMove."+k.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex"),function(H){H.preventDefault();if(k.data("on_drag")){var G=j,J=G.offset(),F=H.originalEvent.pageX-J.left,I=H.originalEvent.pageY-J.top;D(n,o,I,F)}}).bind("MSPointerUp."+k.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex"),function(x){k.data({on_drag:false});j.removeClass("mCSB_dragger_onDrag")})}else{j.bind("mousedown touchstart",function(H){H.preventDefault();H.stopImmediatePropagation();var G=c(this),K=G.offset(),F,J;if(H.type==="touchstart"){var I=H.originalEvent.touches[0]||H.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];F=I.pageX-K.left;J=I.pageY-K.top}else{k.data({on_drag:true});j.addClass("mCSB_dragger_onDrag");F=H.pageX-K.left;J=H.pageY-K.top}if(F<G.width()&&F>0&&J<G.height()&&J>0){n=J;o=F}}).bind("touchmove",function(H){H.preventDefault();H.stopImmediatePropagation();var K=H.originalEvent.touches[0]||H.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],G=c(this),J=G.offset(),F=K.pageX-J.left,I=K.pageY-J.top;D(n,o,I,F)});c(document).bind("mousemove."+k.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex"),function(H){if(k.data("on_drag")){var G=j,J=G.offset(),F=H.pageX-J.left,I=H.pageY-J.top;D(n,o,I,F)}}).bind("mouseup."+k.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex"),function(x){k.data({on_drag:false});j.removeClass("mCSB_dragger_onDrag")})}k.data({bindEvent_scrollbar_drag:true})}function D(G,H,I,F){if(k.data("horizontalScroll")){k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",(j.position().left-(H))+F,{moveDragger:true,trigger:"internal"})}else{k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",(j.position().top-(G))+I,{moveDragger:true,trigger:"internal"})}}if(c.support.touch&&k.data("contentTouchScroll")){if(!k.data("bindEvent_content_touch")){var l,B,r,s,u,C,E;p.bind("touchstart",function(x){x.stopImmediatePropagation();l=x.originalEvent.touches[0]||x.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];B=c(this);r=B.offset();u=l.pageX-r.left;s=l.pageY-r.top;C=s;E=u});p.bind("touchmove",function(x){x.preventDefault();x.stopImmediatePropagation();l=x.originalEvent.touches[0]||x.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];B=c(this).parent();r=B.offset();u=l.pageX-r.left;s=l.pageY-r.top;if(k.data("horizontalScroll")){k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",E-u,{trigger:"internal"})}else{k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",C-s,{trigger:"internal"})}})}}if(!k.data("bindEvent_scrollbar_click")){m.bind("click",function(F){var x=(F.pageY-m.offset().top)*k.data("scrollAmount"),y=c(F.target);if(k.data("horizontalScroll")){x=(F.pageX-m.offset().left)*k.data("scrollAmount")}if(y.hasClass("mCSB_draggerContainer")||y.hasClass("mCSB_draggerRail")){k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",x,{trigger:"internal",scrollEasing:"draggerRailEase"})}});k.data({bindEvent_scrollbar_click:true})}if(k.data("mouseWheel")){if(!k.data("bindEvent_mousewheel")){h.bind("mousewheel",function(H,J){var G,F=k.data("mouseWheelPixels"),x=Math.abs(p.position().top),I=j.position().top,y=m.height()-j.height();if(k.data("normalizeMouseWheelDelta")){if(J<0){J=-1}else{J=1}}if(F==="auto"){F=100+Math.round(k.data("scrollAmount")/2)}if(k.data("horizontalScroll")){I=j.position().left;y=m.width()-j.width();x=Math.abs(p.position().left)}if((J>0&&I!==0)||(J<0&&I!==y)){H.preventDefault();H.stopImmediatePropagation()}G=x-(J*F);k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",G,{trigger:"internal"})});k.data({bindEvent_mousewheel:true})}}if(k.data("scrollButtons_enable")){if(k.data("scrollButtons_scrollType")==="pixels"){if(k.data("horizontalScroll")){v.add(A).unbind("mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown mouseup MSPointerUp mouseout MSPointerOut touchend",i,g);k.data({bindEvent_buttonsContinuous_x:false});if(!k.data("bindEvent_buttonsPixels_x")){v.bind("click",function(x){x.preventDefault();q(Math.abs(p.position().left)+k.data("scrollButtons_scrollAmount"))});A.bind("click",function(x){x.preventDefault();q(Math.abs(p.position().left)-k.data("scrollButtons_scrollAmount"))});k.data({bindEvent_buttonsPixels_x:true})}}else{e.add(w).unbind("mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown mouseup MSPointerUp mouseout MSPointerOut touchend",i,g);k.data({bindEvent_buttonsContinuous_y:false});if(!k.data("bindEvent_buttonsPixels_y")){e.bind("click",function(x){x.preventDefault();q(Math.abs(p.position().top)+k.data("scrollButtons_scrollAmount"))});w.bind("click",function(x){x.preventDefault();q(Math.abs(p.position().top)-k.data("scrollButtons_scrollAmount"))});k.data({bindEvent_buttonsPixels_y:true})}}function q(x){if(!j.data("preventAction")){j.data("preventAction",true);k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",x,{trigger:"internal"})}}}else{if(k.data("horizontalScroll")){v.add(A).unbind("click");k.data({bindEvent_buttonsPixels_x:false});if(!k.data("bindEvent_buttonsContinuous_x")){v.bind("mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown",function(y){y.preventDefault();var x=z();k.data({mCSB_buttonScrollRight:setInterval(function(){k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",Math.abs(p.position().left)+x,{trigger:"internal",scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc"})},17)})});var i=function(x){x.preventDefault();clearInterval(k.data("mCSB_buttonScrollRight"))};v.bind("mouseup touchend MSPointerUp mouseout MSPointerOut",i);A.bind("mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown",function(y){y.preventDefault();var x=z();k.data({mCSB_buttonScrollLeft:setInterval(function(){k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",Math.abs(p.position().left)-x,{trigger:"internal",scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc"})},17)})});var g=function(x){x.preventDefault();clearInterval(k.data("mCSB_buttonScrollLeft"))};A.bind("mouseup touchend MSPointerUp mouseout MSPointerOut",g);k.data({bindEvent_buttonsContinuous_x:true})}}else{e.add(w).unbind("click");k.data({bindEvent_buttonsPixels_y:false});if(!k.data("bindEvent_buttonsContinuous_y")){e.bind("mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown",function(y){y.preventDefault();var x=z();k.data({mCSB_buttonScrollDown:setInterval(function(){k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",Math.abs(p.position().top)+x,{trigger:"internal",scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc"})},17)})});var t=function(x){x.preventDefault();clearInterval(k.data("mCSB_buttonScrollDown"))};e.bind("mouseup touchend MSPointerUp mouseout MSPointerOut",t);w.bind("mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown",function(y){y.preventDefault();var x=z();k.data({mCSB_buttonScrollUp:setInterval(function(){k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",Math.abs(p.position().top)-x,{trigger:"internal",scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc"})},17)})});var f=function(x){x.preventDefault();clearInterval(k.data("mCSB_buttonScrollUp"))};w.bind("mouseup touchend MSPointerUp mouseout MSPointerOut",f);k.data({bindEvent_buttonsContinuous_y:true})}}function z(){var x=k.data("scrollButtons_scrollSpeed");if(k.data("scrollButtons_scrollSpeed")==="auto"){x=Math.round((k.data("scrollInertia")+100)/40)}return x}}}if(k.data("autoScrollOnFocus")){if(!k.data("bindEvent_focusin")){h.bind("focusin",function(){h.scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0);var x=c(document.activeElement);if(x.is("input,textarea,select,button,a[tabindex],area,object")){var G=p.position().top,y=x.position().top,F=h.height()-x.outerHeight();if(k.data("horizontalScroll")){G=p.position().left;y=x.position().left;F=h.width()-x.outerWidth()}if(G+y<0||G+y>F){k.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",y,{trigger:"internal"})}}});k.data({bindEvent_focusin:true})}}if(k.data("autoHideScrollbar")){if(!k.data("bindEvent_autoHideScrollbar")){h.bind("mouseenter",function(x){h.addClass("mCS-mouse-over");d.showScrollbar.call(h.children(".mCSB_scrollTools"))}).bind("mouseleave touchend",function(x){h.removeClass("mCS-mouse-over");if(x.type==="mouseleave"){d.hideScrollbar.call(h.children(".mCSB_scrollTools"))}});k.data({bindEvent_autoHideScrollbar:true})}}},scrollTo:function(e,f){var i=c(this),o={moveDragger:false,trigger:"external",callbacks:true,scrollInertia:i.data("scrollInertia"),scrollEasing:i.data("scrollEasing")},f=c.extend(o,f),p,g=i.children(".mCustomScrollBox"),k=g.children(".mCSB_container"),r=g.children(".mCSB_scrollTools"),j=r.children(".mCSB_draggerContainer"),h=j.children(".mCSB_dragger"),t=draggerSpeed=f.scrollInertia,q,s,m,l;if(!k.hasClass("mCS_no_scrollbar")){i.data({mCS_trigger:f.trigger});if(i.data("mCS_Init")){f.callbacks=false}if(e||e===0){if(typeof(e)==="number"){if(f.moveDragger){p=e;if(i.data("horizontalScroll")){e=h.position().left*i.data("scrollAmount")}else{e=h.position().top*i.data("scrollAmount")}draggerSpeed=0}else{p=e/i.data("scrollAmount")}}else{if(typeof(e)==="string"){var v;if(e==="top"){v=0}else{if(e==="bottom"&&!i.data("horizontalScroll")){v=k.outerHeight()-g.height()}else{if(e==="left"){v=0}else{if(e==="right"&&i.data("horizontalScroll")){v=k.outerWidth()-g.width()}else{if(e==="first"){v=i.find(".mCSB_container").find(":first")}else{if(e==="last"){v=i.find(".mCSB_container").find(":last")}else{v=i.find(e)}}}}}}if(v.length===1){if(i.data("horizontalScroll")){e=v.position().left}else{e=v.position().top}p=e/i.data("scrollAmount")}else{p=e=v}}}if(i.data("horizontalScroll")){if(i.data("onTotalScrollBack_Offset")){s=-i.data("onTotalScrollBack_Offset")}if(i.data("onTotalScroll_Offset")){l=g.width()-k.outerWidth()+i.data("onTotalScroll_Offset")}if(p<0){p=e=0;clearInterval(i.data("mCSB_buttonScrollLeft"));if(!s){q=true}}else{if(p>=j.width()-h.width()){p=j.width()-h.width();e=g.width()-k.outerWidth();clearInterval(i.data("mCSB_buttonScrollRight"));if(!l){m=true}}else{e=-e}}var n=i.data("snapAmount");if(n){e=Math.round(e/n)*n-i.data("snapOffset")}d.mTweenAxis.call(this,h[0],"left",Math.round(p),draggerSpeed,f.scrollEasing);d.mTweenAxis.call(this,k[0],"left",Math.round(e),t,f.scrollEasing,{onStart:function(){if(f.callbacks&&!i.data("mCS_tweenRunning")){u("onScrollStart")}if(i.data("autoHideScrollbar")){d.showScrollbar.call(r)}},onUpdate:function(){if(f.callbacks){u("whileScrolling")}},onComplete:function(){if(f.callbacks){u("onScroll");if(q||(s&&k.position().left>=s)){u("onTotalScrollBack")}if(m||(l&&k.position().left<=l)){u("onTotalScroll")}}h.data("preventAction",false);i.data("mCS_tweenRunning",false);if(i.data("autoHideScrollbar")){if(!g.hasClass("mCS-mouse-over")){d.hideScrollbar.call(r)}}}})}else{if(i.data("onTotalScrollBack_Offset")){s=-i.data("onTotalScrollBack_Offset")}if(i.data("onTotalScroll_Offset")){l=g.height()-k.outerHeight()+i.data("onTotalScroll_Offset")}if(p<0){p=e=0;clearInterval(i.data("mCSB_buttonScrollUp"));if(!s){q=true}}else{if(p>=j.height()-h.height()){p=j.height()-h.height();e=g.height()-k.outerHeight();clearInterval(i.data("mCSB_buttonScrollDown"));if(!l){m=true}}else{e=-e}}var n=i.data("snapAmount");if(n){e=Math.round(e/n)*n-i.data("snapOffset")}d.mTweenAxis.call(this,h[0],"top",Math.round(p),draggerSpeed,f.scrollEasing);d.mTweenAxis.call(this,k[0],"top",Math.round(e),t,f.scrollEasing,{onStart:function(){if(f.callbacks&&!i.data("mCS_tweenRunning")){u("onScrollStart")}if(i.data("autoHideScrollbar")){d.showScrollbar.call(r)}},onUpdate:function(){if(f.callbacks){u("whileScrolling")}},onComplete:function(){if(f.callbacks){u("onScroll");if(q||(s&&k.position().top>=s)){u("onTotalScrollBack")}if(m||(l&&k.position().top<=l)){u("onTotalScroll")}}h.data("preventAction",false);i.data("mCS_tweenRunning",false);if(i.data("autoHideScrollbar")){if(!g.hasClass("mCS-mouse-over")){d.hideScrollbar.call(r)}}}})}if(i.data("mCS_Init")){i.data({mCS_Init:false})}}}function u(w){this.mcs={top:k.position().top,left:k.position().left,draggerTop:h.position().top,draggerLeft:h.position().left,topPct:Math.round((100*Math.abs(k.position().top))/Math.abs(k.outerHeight()-g.height())),leftPct:Math.round((100*Math.abs(k.position().left))/Math.abs(k.outerWidth()-g.width()))};switch(w){case"onScrollStart":i.data("mCS_tweenRunning",true).data("onScrollStart_Callback").call(i,this.mcs);break;case"whileScrolling":i.data("whileScrolling_Callback").call(i,this.mcs);break;case"onScroll":i.data("onScroll_Callback").call(i,this.mcs);break;case"onTotalScrollBack":i.data("onTotalScrollBack_Callback").call(i,this.mcs);break;case"onTotalScroll":i.data("onTotalScroll_Callback").call(i,this.mcs);break}}},stop:function(){var g=c(this),e=g.children().children(".mCSB_container"),f=g.children().children().children().children(".mCSB_dragger");d.mTweenAxisStop.call(this,e[0]);d.mTweenAxisStop.call(this,f[0])},disable:function(e){var j=c(this),f=j.children(".mCustomScrollBox"),h=f.children(".mCSB_container"),g=f.children(".mCSB_scrollTools"),i=g.children().children(".mCSB_dragger");f.unbind("mousewheel focusin mouseenter mouseleave touchend");h.unbind("touchstart touchmove");if(e){if(j.data("horizontalScroll")){i.add(h).css("left",0)}else{i.add(h).css("top",0)}}g.css("display","none");h.addClass("mCS_no_scrollbar");j.data({bindEvent_mousewheel:false,bindEvent_focusin:false,bindEvent_content_touch:false,bindEvent_autoHideScrollbar:false}).addClass("mCS_disabled")},destroy:function(){var e=c(this);e.removeClass("mCustomScrollbar _mCS_"+e.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex")).addClass("mCS_destroyed").children().children(".mCSB_container").unwrap().children().unwrap().siblings(".mCSB_scrollTools").remove();c(document).unbind("mousemove."+e.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex")+" mouseup."+e.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex")+" MSPointerMove."+e.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex")+" MSPointerUp."+e.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex"));c(window).unbind("resize."+e.data("mCustomScrollbarIndex"))}},d={showScrollbar:function(){this.stop().animate({opacity:1},"fast")},hideScrollbar:function(){this.stop().animate({opacity:0},"fast")},mTweenAxis:function(g,i,h,f,o,y){var y=y||{},v=y.onStart||function(){},p=y.onUpdate||function(){},w=y.onComplete||function(){};var n=t(),l,j=0,r=g.offsetTop,s=g.style;if(i==="left"){r=g.offsetLeft}var m=h-r;q();e();function t(){if(window.performance&&window.performance.now){return window.performance.now()}else{if(window.performance&&window.performance.webkitNow){return window.performance.webkitNow()}else{if(Date.now){return Date.now()}else{return new Date().getTime()}}}}function x(){if(!j){v.call()}j=t()-n;u();if(j>=g._time){g._time=(j>g._time)?j+l-(j-g._time):j+l-1;if(g._time<j+1){g._time=j+1}}if(g._time<f){g._id=_request(x)}else{w.call()}}function u(){if(f>0){g.currVal=k(g._time,r,m,f,o);s[i]=Math.round(g.currVal)+"px"}else{s[i]=h+"px"}p.call()}function e(){l=1000/60;g._time=j+l;_request=(!window.requestAnimationFrame)?function(z){u();return setTimeout(z,0.01)}:window.requestAnimationFrame;g._id=_request(x)}function q(){if(g._id==null){return}if(!window.requestAnimationFrame){clearTimeout(g._id)}else{window.cancelAnimationFrame(g._id)}g._id=null}function k(B,A,F,E,C){switch(C){case"linear":return F*B/E+A;break;case"easeOutQuad":B/=E;return -F*B*(B-2)+A;break;case"easeInOutQuad":B/=E/2;if(B<1){return F/2*B*B+A}B--;return -F/2*(B*(B-2)-1)+A;break;case"easeOutCubic":B/=E;B--;return F*(B*B*B+1)+A;break;case"easeOutQuart":B/=E;B--;return -F*(B*B*B*B-1)+A;break;case"easeOutQuint":B/=E;B--;return F*(B*B*B*B*B+1)+A;break;case"easeOutCirc":B/=E;B--;return F*Math.sqrt(1-B*B)+A;break;case"easeOutSine":return F*Math.sin(B/E*(Math.PI/2))+A;break;case"easeOutExpo":return F*(-Math.pow(2,-10*B/E)+1)+A;break;case"mcsEaseOut":var D=(B/=E)*B,z=D*B;return A+F*(0.499999999999997*z*D+-2.5*D*D+5.5*z+-6.5*D+4*B);break;case"draggerRailEase":B/=E/2;if(B<1){return F/2*B*B*B+A}B-=2;return F/2*(B*B*B+2)+A;break}}},mTweenAxisStop:function(e){if(e._id==null){return}if(!window.requestAnimationFrame){clearTimeout(e._id)}else{window.cancelAnimationFrame(e._id)}e._id=null},rafPolyfill:function(){var f=["ms","moz","webkit","o"],e=f.length;while(--e>-1&&!window.requestAnimationFrame){window.requestAnimationFrame=window[f[e]+"RequestAnimationFrame"];window.cancelAnimationFrame=window[f[e]+"CancelAnimationFrame"]||window[f[e]+"CancelRequestAnimationFrame"]}}};d.rafPolyfill.call();c.support.touch=!!("ontouchstart" in window);c.support.msPointer=window.navigator.msPointerEnabled;var a=("https:"==document.location.protocol)?"https:":"http:";c.event.special.mousewheel||document.write('<script src="'+a+'//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.0.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"><\/script>');c.fn.mCustomScrollbar=function(e){if(b[e]){return b[e].apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1))}else{if(typeof e==="object"||!e){return b.init.apply(this,arguments)}else{c.error("Method "+e+" does not exist")}}}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to suggest an answer if we could see your code!

Comment: Aw , sorry I forgot about it, adding.